# Find possible value to perfect square number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all possible values for x, such that  $1391- \sqrt{x}$ is a perfect square.

I know the answer is 484, but I don't have any idea for that.

Comment: @GitGud $x$ is an integer because if $n^2 = 1391-\sqrt{x}$, then $x = (1391-n^2)^2$.

Comment: @rewritten Yes, of course.

Comment: As written, the question is asking for a set, not the number of elements in the set.  I find many fewer elements than $484$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $x$ is a perfect square, a number $n$ exists for which $n^2=x$. Insert this into your original formula.

$1391 - \sqrt{x} = n^2$

$ - \sqrt{x} = n^2 - 1391$

$\sqrt{x} = - n^2 + 1391$

$x = (- n^2 + 1391 )^2$

Answer (score 1):

for any natural number $n ≤ 37$, you can solve easily

$$
1391-\sqrt{x} = n^2
$$

by just solving it (as $0 < n^2 < 1391$) with

$$
1391 - n^2 = \sqrt{x} \\
x = (1391 - n^2)^2
$$

so you have exactly 38 solutions